# Gio Mount Returns Different Outputs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, gio

I'm trying to make python script for mounting using Gio Module, however when i add my script to crontab or run it as a service, i only get filesystem root:

**In shell:**

```
gio mount -l
```

returns every mountable drive and volume,

however, when i run:

```
sudo gio mount -l

or 

sudo -u myuser gio mount -l
```

i only get Filesystem root and floppy.

The difference i realized is,

sudo, or my script auto ran by system returns the volumes with type "GUnixVolume",

and just "gio mount -l" returns type GProxyDrive.

So what is the difference, and how can i detect external drives when my script is ran by system?